# Что конкретно делает метод Thread.SpinWait?

Tags: c#, .net

Из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait(v=vs.110).aspx) откровенно говоря ничего непонятно, все очень сумбурно. Что именно делает этот метод?

Comment: Что непонятного-то? Используется для блокировки, только вместо усыпления потока запускает в нём цикл, количество итераций идёт параметром метода. Использование напрямую не особо нужно, гораздо удобнее использовать Monitor.Enter, он всё равно внутри использует его

Comment: @AntonShakalo, запускает в нем цикл, хорошо. Предположим цикл с 1 итерацией. Непонятен этот момент: " SpinWait по существу переводит процессор в очень непрерывном цикле счетчик цикла, определяемого iterations параметр. Длительность ожидания таким образом зависит от скорости процессора."

Comment: Второй момент, который непонятен, это: "В редких случаях, где удобно во избежание переключения контекста, например, если известно, что изменение состояния приближается Позвонить SpinWait метод в цикле. Код SpinWait выполняет предназначен для предотвращения проблем, возникающих на компьютерах с несколькими процессорами. Например, на компьютерах с несколькими процессорами Intel используют технологии Hyper-Threading SpinWait предотвращает перегрузка процессора в определенных ситуациях."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Русский машинный перевод не очень хорош, лучше смотреть в [свежий английский оригинал](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.spinwait?view=netframework-4.7#remarks):

> `SpinWait` essentially puts the processor into a very tight loop, with the loop count specified by the `iterations` parameter. The duration of the wait therefore depends on the speed of the processor.

то есть

> `SpinWait` на самом деле просто выполняет холостой цикл, количество итераций которого равно параметру `iterations`. Продолжительность ожидания, таким образом, зависит от скорости процессора.

Для чего такое может понадобиться? Например, для оптимизации блокировки: если заблокированный ресурс скорее всего будет через несколько тактов процессора освобождён, то имеет смысл перед уходом на ожидание в режим ядра (что является медленной операцией) прокрутить несколько холостых циклов в надежде, что ресурс за это время освободится. Именно это делает `lock`/`Monitor.Enter`.